# 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/660/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, August 24th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 6):

What is your opinion of the role of the Magento StackExchange in relation to third-party extensions--both free and commercial?

Answer (score 4):

Do you think you can/should help keeping the answered question rate high as a moderator? If yes, how would you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Moderators have a decisive vote when it comes to closing questions, opening questions, validating edits.
This means a moderator can close a question without the need for other 4 votes.
What's your view on that? Does it change anything, does it make you pay more attention to what you are reviewing? or it doesn't make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 2):

Many users are not native English speakers, they are not confident (or seem hard) to post a completely question. How will you do to encourage them to post questions regardless language matters?

Answer (score 1):

How would you react with users who shamelessly posted stupid question/doing this job for me type of question.

How would you react with those users?

Answer (score 1):

- Moderators frequently have to deal with content from user new to Magento and to StackExchange. What will you regularly do as a moderator with regards to these users?

Comment: from the OP: "Please only post one question per answer." :)

Comment: "As a moderator, will you remove answers, delete comments, etc. when they point out you're an idiot?"

Comment: And I, as a moderator I will try to educate before taking distructive measures.

Answer (score 1):

- Moderators have several tools at their disposal to educate users and to ensure the quality of content. How would you rank the various activities of moderators?

Answer (score 1):

In phase 2 of the graduation, the "trusted user" privilege will be gained at 20K reputation instead of 4k.

This means, the number of users that can vote to delete questions and answers with negative score suddenly drops from 23 to 3 and the responsibility to decide about deletion is shifted more towards the moderators (at least for some time).

How do you feel about this responsibility and what's your policy on deleting posts?

Answer (score 0):

What do you believe is your most important role as a moderator **specifically for this exchange** - in your personal opinion and from a community perspective?

Answer (score -1):

On Magento StackExchange, there're many questions take time to write the answers. Some users are able to answer but they don't have time (or they think it would take much time) to write down, then they don't answer at all.

How will/would you do to deal with this?