# Cannot vote on closing questions anymore until 3k rep

Tags: discussion, reputation, vote-to-close

Has something happened to our Magento SE? Is anything done to the voting reputation limit while the site is piloting in this in between beta/out-of-beta state?

I have just over 2k rep and highly active in reviewing, but I cannot review Close Votes and Reopen Votes as it says:

> You need at least 3k reputation to review reopen votes.

<del>So help me to 3k!</del> No seriously, what has happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug. Specifically, entirely my fault - I renamed the setting that overrides normal privilege thresholds for graduated sites and keeps them at the public beta levels. I forgot that the setting values don't get moved over in the rename, so the thresholds jumped up.

I restored the correct settings here and on other sites that have been graduated under the new design-independent system, so everything should be back to normal.

Sorry!

Comment: Have an upvote!

Answer (score 4):

This was covered earlier in moderator elections as a "what would you do" question:

> In phase 2 of the graduation, the "trusted user" privilege will be gained at 20K reputation instead of 4k. This means, the number of users that can vote to delete questions and answers with negative score suddenly drops from 23 to 3 and the responsibility to decide about deletion is shifted more towards the moderators (at least for some time). How do you feel about this responsibility and what's your policy on deleting posts?

Trusted user privilege and other privs are granted at higher point thresholds now.

---

Source: [2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/660/336)

Comment: Aha! So that has gone into effect just now...