# 2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

Magento is scheduled for an election [next week, February 19th](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/2). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Unlike [last time](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/637/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), we're hosting the question collection a week in advance, so that not only can folks start prepping questions in advance, but also potential candidates can think about nominating themselves and seeing the questions they'll have an opening to answer.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, February 19th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 14):

What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 3):

Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?

Answer (score 3):

What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

Answer (score 1):

How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on stack exchange ?

Comment: Like this ... :)

Answer (score 1):

How you handle situation where newbie regularly ask some random questions which is not related to MagentoSE?

Answer (score 1):

How much time you can spend per day for the community ?

Answer (score 0):

Moderators are expected to spend only 30 mins of their time, but we all know that 30 mins is insufficient. There are hundreds of flags per day in the queue, a few of them needing 10~15 minutes. Would you be able to scale up your work time when the demand increases?

Comment: There are not hundreds of flags / day. Where did you get that?

Comment: @Marius It is Just my assumptions, feel free to correct me.

Comment: OK. There are about 10 to 20 flags a day, but not all off them require the same amount of time spent on them. There are the simple ones where answers are not really answers. this can be easily deleted in seconds. But there are the ones for copied answers that require investigation (1-2 minutes). Then there are spam flags that require further investigation  of the user being flagged. Also actions may be required on these ones. Contacting users, suspension, checking the user's accounts on other websites and notifying the other website mods if the user has the similar behavior on other websites.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know of insight of moderation,useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

How many times in a day you visit meta site?

Comment: Not sure this is relevant since the moderators get notified when a new question is posted on meta.

Comment: OK @Marius, I don't know about this feature

Answer (score 0):

What's your reaction when you find some people doing immoral things?

Comment: This is a very subjective question, particularly because what is considered immoral and moral is wildly different based on culture, EG some people believe eating animals is immoral. Instead I think "Immoral" should be substituted for "prohibited"

Comment: @John , This question is just my opinion, based on situation that I have faced in past, Its completely ok if you dont agree with my questions

Comment: It's not a disagreement as such it's just I'd find it very hard to measure how good a response is, what level of immorality are we speaking here?

Comment: @John Here I mean something when you copy paste someone answer without giving them a credit

Comment: Understood, point taken.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you feel you are apt to the moderator position?