# 2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

Not every question was selected - we picked the 8 upvoted submissions, plus two of our bonus questions, for a total of 10 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/f263a66f-d11f-49ec-96fb-1fdfd49de138/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

---

> 1. What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the reasons.
> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 4. What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?
> 5. Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?
> 6. How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?
> 7. How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?
> 8. How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?
> 9. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?
> 10. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Answer (score 55):

#### AMIT BERA

> 1.What is your position on questions related to third-party modules? A
>   simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the
>   reasons.

*If third party modules is open source and have enough details in the question then I have allowed them. For all other cases, I will against them.*

> 2.How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of
>   valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of
>   arguments/flags from comments:

*In this case, I will put a comment and will suggest to other users to review the question and put my point of view.*

***Also,Will tell them to come on chat room and try to understand the reasons of them and will shortout them.***

> 3.How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc
>   a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

*I will discuss with them in the chat room and try to explain with my point of view why we should delete a question.Then we will take the final discussion to continue with current state or will open the question again.*

> 4.What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between
>   quality content and being welcoming to new members?

**Welcome the new user to by putting a comment.**

*Trying to guide them and edit their content and **give the upvotes on there Q/A and give helpful flag on comment encouraging to contribute to the community***

> 5.Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you
>   get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach
>   to such no-do actions/activities?

First, suggest them to do not do anything wrong and respect to the other and then temporarily suspended those accounts.

> 6.How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think
>   you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load
>   for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not
>   available?

Available 2-3 hours every day and will spend more when I will have free time. **MSE is my hobby**

Yes, the whenever flag is loaded then I will be available.

> 7.How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack
>   Exchange?

*First, edit their answers and improve the content.That is the best way to improve answers of a developer*. I am **too confident they will do not same** mistake again in the **future** .***Also upvote the answer.***

> 8.How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?

- First, try to give the answers to those questions.
- Then give some reference links relative StackExchange website/ Stackoverflow
- Last, put a flag as Offtopic on those questions and put a comment the reason of offtopic.*

> 9.In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more
>   effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

10K /20k scores do not matter.If, the person will do their job edit, flag, the review then that is the most important point as a moderator.

> 10.In your opinion, what do moderators do?

keep run MSE on the same track and Make MSE as opensource to All  :) Encourage all users

Comment: This is a serios question ... _"10K /20k scores do not matter."_ Whats the difference of being moderator? With your ~50k REP you have acces to all features (please correct me if im wrong!)

Comment: Good luck Amit.

Comment: My vote goes to you..best man
good luck

Comment: Thanks, Rahul...

Comment: My vote also goes to you.. @AmitBera

Comment: thanks Pushpendra

Comment: you have a knowledge and you are sharing and solving problems thats a big contribution bro..I voted for you

Comment: My vote's for you.

Comment: my vote for you  Good luck @AmitBera

Comment: I've seen you around the Magento community for many years now. You've certainly got my vote!

Comment: Thanks to all :)

Comment: Buddy i know  you always try be helpfull...All the best @AmitBera

Comment: Good Luck dear :)

Comment: i vote you for 1st choice.you have help me a lot in this forum and your web.good luck Amit Bera

Comment: thanks to  to all...

Answer (score 35):

---

> 1. What is your position on questions related to third-party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not suffice. Please list the reasons.

If it can be reproduced without actually having the module (so enough code was posted etc) or if it's a popular free module with a high chance of answering I'm more than ok with it. If it's some obscure paid module it's better to just contact their support.

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

That's what the chat is for. Especially if it's quick back and forth comments.
Talk it out in the chatroom, exchange emails, share skype details.... 
As long as they post the final answer on MSE again.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Get upset, ignore said mod, rant on twitter about she or he. You know, the normal, adult way of dealing with other people.
Or maybe just ping 'em real quick and see if we can discuss it

> 4. What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

Explain why we write questions in a certain way, take the time, maybe suggest some edits. A lot of us are not writing in their native language and new members might not be familiar with the whole concept of asking clear, reproducible questions so a bit of guidance might go a long way.

> 5. Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?

Discuss it with the person in question, try to reason, find out why they behave in a certain way and see if there is anything they need help with.
If that fails I'd take it up with the other mods and decide on a course of action.

> 6. How much time can you spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?

on average 30 to 60 minutes on flags etc wouldn't be an issue. If more is occasionally needed I guess I can do with a little less sleep for a night.
Comments might get a bit grumpier than normal tho. I need my sleep

> 7. How can you help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?

Guide on how to explain to others what steps to take, how to write down the train of thought that led you to a solution and post code and testable results.

> 8. How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?

Try and explain to the user what the purpose is of the forum and suggest other places that might give him better answers like StackOverflow.
If the user keeps posting I guess a chat with the other mods and more decicive action is required.

> 9. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

A mod shouldn't be in it for the rep. Moderators do the tasks others might not do in my opinion. review flags, play arbiter, help other users to improve their questions and answers.

> 10. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

See previous answer ;)
I don't think a moderator should police to much, or correct every typo, etc. A moderator should be in the background making the community a more fun place for everyone involved.

Comment: I really like your answers.

Answer (score 21):

### Miguel Balparda

> 1. What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the reasons.

As long as it's something you can reproduce, I'll allow it. If it's OSS, GitHub is preferred but since this is something that can be used in favor of a greater audience it might work

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

As long as it's polite and doesn't cause others to leave, using the site's features should be encouraged.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Talk with the other mod probably. Consensus is good but having some discussion is better.

> 4. What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

Showing people the guidelines and have them respect it no matter what.

> 5. Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?

Being disrespectful or insulting others is a no go, a code of conduct might work to better define those. No-do = ban, maybe temporary.

> 6. How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?

2-4 hs and can scale when needed.

> 7. How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?

By explaining devs that other devs might have the same issue they are having right now in the future and having a complete answer is going to beextremely helpful to them.

> 8. How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?

First explain what's wrong, then if it continues to do it, close or try to move questions to an appropriate site.

> 9. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

By getting to know more people. Resolving controversies and moderating takes time and people is involved instead of just computers.

> 10. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

I thought Marius was traveling the globe while being a millionaire as a moderator but once I met him in Las Vegas and asked about it he also told me he has a Magento branded airplane, so there is that.

Comment: Dude...about #10...Don't tell everyone.

Answer (score 18):

> 1.What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not suffice. Please list the reasons.

Mostly I am against them, but if the op add the relevant code and if I am familiar with extension , I will answer happily. It is better to answer than to close it. But rules say third party are not recommended.

> 2.How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

I simply move their comments to chat.

> 3.How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I will ask the opinion of mode about that why he closed/deleted/etc a question. Then I will try to convince him what is my opinion about that. I will compare my approach with his reasons-- if the grounds and reasons are solid , it is ok ! Otherwise I will ask him to give a second thought to his decision.

> 4.What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

It is extemely important to welcome and encourage new commers , mostly they do ask questions without keeping quality in mind. I will add comment for improving the question or simple modify myself question.

> 5.Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?

There is no tolerance in no-do activities. Must he warn user and he consistently doing  then ban.

> 6.How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?

I currently doing one hour daily on MSE. But if no moderator available i will be here 24/7 to help the community.

> 7.How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?

I will ask him to do the best formating and to the point answer.

> 8.How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?

I will guide him to use proper community for that.

> 9.In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

After reaching the 20k rep i still have limited privilege and cannot do more actions. After become mod you will do quick  actions with freedom.

> 10.In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Keep the community clean and encourage community member to participate more.

Comment: Good luck Qaisar

Answer (score 15):

### [sv3n](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-214302)

> 1. What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the reasons.

For closed-source extensions at least a few lines of code have to be written - otherwise it is not reproducible and should be closed.

I don't have any problems with open-source modules - after all, it's not much different than writing your own code. *Advantage*, I can look at the whole code if necessary. Nevertheless, the affected code should also be posted here. A link to the repo could also be helpful.

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

[flag] Unclear what you're asking.

Depends on situation ... if it's to "chatty" move to chat or ask to improve the question, if rude/impolite give a warning, ... ?

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

If you don't agree, it's the same like flag it as *"in need of moderator intervention "* and talk to each other.

> 4. What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

<s>Nothing</s>. Not to much. I don't think that 1, 2 or 3 moderators have such an influence on the quality of the content. This is due to the community itself. *

There are several questions about this topic on the meta page ... Read them, discuss them and act to fit them.

After all, you're "only" a moderator - and not the only one. Keep things tidy. Setting a good example ...

<sup>* In general I agree with it https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-214246, but this is something where the *community* could also use more votes (ups and downs) to *honor* good/bad questions/answers. Think this could keep the quality high.... it's not a mod thing.</sup>

> 5. Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?

The rules that exist must be enforced (do not spam/advertise/cheat).  Depending on what it's about suspend or ban account. For *minor* misbehaviour talk to them first.

> 6. How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?

Too much ;) Hard to tell ...  +4h? There is always a MSE tab opened in browser ... just to check new questions, flag or review flags. So no, i'can't scale up. :)

> 7. How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?

Either leave a comment or try to give a *better* answer yourself.

> 8. How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?

If it's easy and fast to answer, try to give an answer, but I'd flag/close it as off-topic (or with a custom message that is displayed as comment).

> 9. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

<s>Nothing. The election was started because someone thought that Marius might need some support.</s>

The only useful thing was to get 2k REP to edit posts yourself, the rest are gimmicks. Out of curiosity I would only be interested in the server stats:)

OK ... sometimes it might be better to have the possiblity to close/delete/reopen things direclty ...

That was wrong... there's a lot to do in the background. So, it would make me more effective, because I could have the possiblity to help the community right now - not in some months/yeaers when I reached 10/20k rep.

> 10. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

The same as many others do. Keep things tidy. Just a little more flexible.  **Edit:** I think it is underestimated, but there's a lot to do in background ... review  deleted questions/answers, finally delete posts that are flagged for.

Comment: Best opinions so far. Loved it. Best of luck.

Comment: Good luck sv3n.

Answer (score 12):

### [**Murtuza Zabuawala**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/29731/murtuza-zabuawala)

> 1. What is your position on questions related to third party modules?

If OP has included Some part of code from which we could identify problem then I welcome that question, otherwise I do not recommend this type of question,
Then also I wait for 2-3 days for this type of question if some one wants to answer, if there is no one to answer to that question then I will close that question

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

I would advice him/her to use chat room facility, even after 2-3 advice they do not change their behavior then I will send them a warning Message that your account could be suspend for a week.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Here In Magento SE mods are very talented they always put a comment why they delete a post, but when they don't, and I don't understand the logic why they delete the post then I will ask them directly and tell my opinion about the post

> 4. What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

I will guide to newbie how to ask quality question that could easily answerable, with some edits I will teach and also put a comment that they have to include some part of a code

> 5. Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?

Yes, I have seen many no do activities like fraud voting, I have flagged those post previously and mod has taken action against them, I will do the same who is doing such fraud activities

> 6. How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?

while I am a wake I always provide 10-12 minutes in every hour, and 15-20 minutes in morning time

> 7. How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?

I will tell them what are the best practice to ask a question and tell them what they have tried so far put them in a question  so that way other can understand the code

> 8. How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?

I will close his/her questions for first few occasions, and if they don't learn from this I will warn them and even worst scenario I will suspend their account for a week

> 9. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

I am very close to 10k reputation mark just 300hits away,

In 10k reputation You can cast only 3 delete votes in a day.while as a mod this limitation is not there, same goes for close votes/Low quality post/ suggested edits right now I can cast maximum 20 votes in a day. which is not sufficient Magestackday kind of activity

and when I see no-do activities I can not take action right away. I need to wait for mod to take actions.

> 10. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Keep site more clear, and encourage every one to take equal participation in site

Answer (score 11):

### [PRINCE PATEL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/35758/prince-patel)

> What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A
>   simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the
>   reasons.

If the OP provides sufficient data to identify the issue of the code in question without any other details of the third party module then I would welcome the question otherwise it's better to close that question.

> How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of
>   valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of
>   arguments/flags from comments?

There would be couple of steps that I would suggest in this scenario

**Firstly** what I Would do is to check the profile of the user by analyzing arguments/flag on the other answers. If the **same behavior persists on multiple answers** then I will provide him a warning followed by a suspension of the user account for some time period.

**Secondly,** if this behavior is observed on single answers then would **suggest using chat room** for this. If then also the user doesn't respond than will send him/her a warning message and then suspend the user account.

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc
>   a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Here at Magento SE, mods are already well versed with Magento. If I don't find any comments on the deleted Question and I feel the particular question is helpful to other users then I will convey my opinion to mod and will try to convince him/her about the importance and helpfulness of the question.

> What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve the balance
>   between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

It's important to welcome new members to the community.

**Frequently new members stop posting a question on the SE** if they are not able to find the solution to their problems.

So what **I would suggest is to create a new thread and posting all unanswered, high voted question** on that so that the users can get another look on the question if in case they missed it a first time and the chances of resolution increases.

Also, **I would request the New members who only post their queries to contribute to the SE by solving a question.**

> Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you
>   get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach
>   to such no-do actions/activities?

Yes, I have seen no do actions/activities like deleting own multiple questions answers, Unwnted commenting, Fraud voting. But he/she must be warned before ban or suspend.

> How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think
>   you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load
>   for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not
>   available?

I have SE open in my web browser all the time I am logged in to my computer. And I am basically logged in 24/7 expect the time I am asleep thats around 6 hr. So I can be the help at any time if the mod is not available.

> How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack
>   Exchange?

I will tell what are the best practices and do proper formatting to get point on the answer and explain that his/her answers are useful for many other users.

> How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks
>   questions that are not related to Magento?

Firstly I will close the question as per the basic rule of Magento SE. And I will suggest him to post the question in the proper community.

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more
>   effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

I am already 1311 points away from 10K mark and rapidly decreasing, But as a normal user, I have access to limited privileges to do the critical operation. And being a mod will provide me this access. And I will be able to serve the community in a better way.

> In your opinion, what do moderators do?

There are a couple of things that Mod take care here at community Such as Make the community clean and clear, Help new/existing members with their issues.

**In my opinion, moderators are the main part of the community and are responsible to make community clean and clear.**

Comment: good answers. Hope to see you moderator soon. Good luck Prince

Comment: Thanks Jai...:)

Comment: always my vote for you bro Good luck @PrincePatel

Comment: Thanks @RakeshDonga

Answer (score 6):

### Circle Six

> 1. What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the reasons.

Users come to the site with a lot of misconceptions about the scope of Magento and often feel as though their access and system is universal. Most issue with 3rd party modules have to be addressed by the module developer as no one in the community has direct experience with that code. But my goal as a moderator would be to help educate users of the site as a whole with each answer so no one feels as if they are being ignored or talked down to. Once the issue has clearly been explained with the 3rd party module, if there is no clear solution, my goal is to help shepherd the user where they can get help instead of just saying "we can't help you here".

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

We have to allow people the be who they are, that being said, confrontational personalities often push away users that are confused about a problem and need help. There is no one answer, but as we are looking to help people here, helping people be kinder to each other falls into that scope. So contacting the person about the comments on a case by case basis is the right approach. We are a world wide community and what is rude in one part of the world is common parlance in others. So it's about the conversation of making this site better person by person and not just one solution.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Similar to my answer above, these issue have to be set on a case by case basis. Sometime this is the case where a moderator didn't have time to fully explain why a question is closed/deleted/etc, and it just take a little time to dig in and see what's happening. Other times it might just take engaging with the person asking the question to get a better understanding what they are after to reformat or post another question that gets at the issue.

> 4. What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

Engagement with the users. The Magento community is a very welcoming and helpful. Our site doesn't suffer a lot of the flames of other sites because we all come at this framework as a "one for all and all for one" attitude. I have found personalty that when we engage with people, they are happy to step up their questions and answers to fit our standard and create better content with positive encouragement.

> 5. Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?

Of course we have to protect against abusive behavior. There is no room here for people that. Also protecting people's intellectual property and making sure that code isn't being ripped off.

> 6. How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?

Right now i spend 2-3 hours a day (mostly) reading and writing on the site. I am more then willing to scale up my efforts as my day job fully supports my work on Magento Stacks.

> 7. How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?

With clear and concise communication about the site standard and using examples of exceptional questions are the gold standard for what we do on the site.

> 8. How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?

Begin with flagging the questions with comments to explain to the user how their questions are unrelated and pointing them in the correct place for the help they need. If the problem persist i would clean up the site from any unrelated questions as our standards dictate.

> 9. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

A large part of the reason i work on Magento stacks is to help educate myself on the framework. New question can show a view of the system that I would not naturally come across in my daily work. I like to dig into the problems and understand the solution to reinforce the work I do. As much as I enjoy helping people with problem, the main benefit to me is exercising and practicing my craft as a collaboration with everyone on the site. This makes me a stronger developer and pushes my skills and career forward.

> 10. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

They act as shepherds for all the site users, helping when people need help, cleaning up when there is a mess and holding people to the site standards as defined by the site and community. They also act as the "face" of the site and need to uphold the integrity of the site so that people maintain respect for the site and each other.

Comment: One question.. is circle six your real name? If not, do you think a moderator need a nick name/cover? Btw I love all of your opinions above. Good luck.

Comment: It is not my real name. and i though i had my real name in my profile, but it's not there as i just checked. circlesix is just what i go by, but it's not to hide my identity, it's just when you are named Mike, no one knows who you are because everyone is named Mike......

Comment: Updated my profile: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/34621/circlesix?tab=profile

Comment: It's always good to see new faces around here!

On #4 - Love your passion for engagement.

On #1 - Your response is a bit unclear to me. How would you _shepherd_ in a situation where no answer for the OP is apparent? Are there practical rules to follow for delivering an effective question? Give an example of how you might educate a seemingly helpless OP.

Comment: I'm talking about doing general research into the module itself and seeing what support they offer or if they have good support. The module env of magento is pretty close nit community, so most devs have had some exp with different companies. But more generally, i have found helping people finds it's own path, sometimes dead ends, but rarely. If the OP is willing to work to the solution, a path "reveals" (ooooo, spooky!) itself, even if it's a code base we don't have access to.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for going a little deeper on that one.

Answer (score 6):

### [Keyur Shah](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2589/keyur-shah)

> 1. What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the reasons.

If the answer contains only link with third party module or if answer contains self promotion then I strongly against them but If the answer contain with proper description and link then I welcome the answer and I also welcome the answer with GitHub link because sometimes It is difficult to write whole answer from Github

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

I believe conversion always helps to solve the problem and this situation MSE provides chat feature to keep it simple.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

In that case I like to do conversion with another mod so I can understand the root cause of closed/deleted/etc and I can also share my point of view to solve this situation.

> 4. What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

I think In Stack-Overflow you can find posts(how to write proper answer or question etc.) with link so you can guide new MSE members with proper link to maintain quality content and welcome comment is also good way.

> 5. Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no-do actions/activities?

I personally don't like to ban any user so If I find any comment/answer or any fraud user/voting which is disrespectful then I will flag this with proper description if its needed then I will add question in meta site (so people can share his/her point of view ). And still If I find(after warning) then I will ban user for temp.

> 6. How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?

It is totally depend on situation but generally I can spend 2-3 hours even more then this. Also in my browser you can find MSE link as pin tab so it always entourage me to check this site very often :)

> 7. How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?

By just writing comment so he/she can understand that still answer need Improvement or by improving format or updating broken link(if answer has any link)

> 8. How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions that are not related to Magento?

First I will check if its related to Magento or not if not then I will add comment and mark question as close or moved(If it can be be move to another stack-overflow site)

> 9. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

I believe that reputation always matters because It gives you some special privilege(delete comment, answer etc.) :)

> 10. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Try to make community clean , encourage new members with question or answer

Answer (score 3):

[**MANOJ DESWAL**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/54588/manoj-deswal?tab=profile)

> 1) What is your position on questions related to third party modules?
>   A simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the
>   reasons.

In my opinion, it's totally depends on the quality of code/module if that can be reproduced and enough details are given then I will allow that as a user I always come here with hope of getting the solution so until or unless we can help I will allow them.

> 2) How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of
>   valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of
>   arguments/flags from comments?

At this moment I prefer chat until or unless user is not harming the community , sometime I prefer sharing personal details like skype and helping the user as I did no of times

> 3) How would you handle a situation where another mod
>   closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

At first instance that can be little annoying but each one of us can have different thought process so if needed to reopen a question then a polite chat can work in good way.

> 4.What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

New members should be warmly welcomed as I wanted when enter in community , guide them like editing content , voting to encourage and answering and commenting to help them out

> 5) Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you
>   get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach
>   to such no-do actions/activities?

The first thing come in my mind is stop fraud voting users do for downgrading or upgrading scores of others , second users who are promoting their personal services here should be suspended from communities.

> 6) How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think
>   you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load
>   for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not
>   available?

I almost spend 5-6 hours daily, As this is source for me learning and solving my problems so I actively contribute my quality time.

> 7) How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on
>   Stack Exchange?

I prefer editing the content and improving the formatting as required so user developer will see how it should have looked . And little encouragement by up voting do the rest of work.

> 8) How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks
>   questions that are not related to Magento?

This is sometime annoying thing , in this case closing the questions or pointing out the things should work and if this fails too then suspending the account will make her/him understand that what he should't do

> 9) In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more
>   effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

For rep work only to get a privilege, so I prefer improving the community by commenting , editing , closing , reopening and reviewing flags. So if I have powers to do these things then rep doesn't matter much

> 10) In your opinion, what do moderators do?

In my opinion, moderators keep eye on cleaning the community or encouraging the users to participate

Comment: I think moderators are made in this community to help others in learning and finding new things  which will make this community more. So, closing the questions and  then suspending the account will not be more encourage-able

Comment: Yes this one side duty learning and finding new things ,but as everything has two side so have to take care of another side as well.. if someone continue to fraud vote , posting spam answers ..so their strict action is required and this is for good will of community not for moderator ..

Comment: How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments

Comment: @VisakhBSujathan I already mentioned in answer that creating long comment list , let's deal the problem/solution inside chat or possible then will try to tackle personally .

Answer (score 2):

**Pradeep Kumar**

> What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A
>   simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the
>   reasons.

i am for on third party module questions. by seeing the questions we can tell its magento code issue or very specific to the module issue , if its magento level code issue we can solve it and give approach to solve the issue , if its very specific then we will inform them to close the issue and raise the issue in that module provider website

> How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of
>   valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of
>   arguments/flags from comments?

if the arguments comments are more then 5 and related to that issue the we tell both user use chat or contact personally.
if the comments leads to other issue then main issue we will inform them to create new post on that

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc
>   a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

i will contact them and ask the reason, if the given reason then correct then fine else i will explain him in my point view and make it open

> What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between
>   quality content and being welcoming to new members?

we ill make answers are clear and less thread in each post , if the post has more then 5 answer we will delete the answer which is not correct and clear

> Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you
>   get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach
>   to such no-do actions/activities?

we will ask them why there are no actions  and if the are valid user we will ask  them spend every day 10 mins to solve few issue and be active in community 
if they are not valid suspend the user

> How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think
>   you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load
>   for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not
>   available?

very 3 hours i can spend  15 mins, to see new post  and answers
if got solution post immediately

> How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack
>   Exchange?

when ever we see new post or answer we will try to see the quality of post, when ever i will feel it should be improve we ill inform him that you can modify the post this way so it will me more clear

> How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks
>   questions that are not related to Magento?

first few time we will warn them , still they follow same thing we will suspend there account

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more
>   effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

very simple i am never behind rep count ,i just spend time to post  more questions  and answer

> In your opinion, what do moderators do?

keep post very clear, make sure all post are related to Magento, when ever found fraud user just take action , and try to spend more time in community

Comment: In most of your opinions, I can see a severe/strict way of approach. Why do you feel a moderator should be strict?

Comment: if the user is fraud , needs to be strict, else in other case  moderator should not be strict

Comment: I think you misunderstood #2 "How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?" It's not about generating arguments in ONE post, but in general

Comment: I think moderators are made in this community to help others in learning how the community is working & make this community grew. So, always pursuing a strict behavior with the other members will not be more encourage-able

Answer (score 2):

[Naveenbos](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2132/naveenbos)

> What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A
>   simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the
>   reasons.

I am for them because,Users are coming here for getting solutions including me,if the question is clear and all informations are there, then the question is genuine,so either we can give solution or we can help them to solve the problem by giving some inputs

> How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of
>   valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of
>   arguments/flags from comments?

For the unwanted flags and comments we can give warning to that user, also we can suggest to use chat, if he is not willing to do that, we can block that user.

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc
>   a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I just ask the reason for delete or close that question, may be user got answer from his research, in that case i suggest them to post that answer, so some one can use it in future, other reason for that lack of visibility of that question, may be some wordings that used in that question, so moderator can give suggestions to do it in a better way.

> What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance
>   between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

We should try encourage them to ask questions,thorough the upvotes on there QA and edit their questions, we should always keep welcome the new comers.

> Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you
>   get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach
>   to such no-do actions/activities?

Suspend the account.

> How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think
>   you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load
>   for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not
>   available?

1-2hrs Maximum

> How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack
>   Exchange?

Suggest them do formatting the wordings and yes it should be the point to the answer

> How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks
>   questions that are not related to Magento?

If it is not related to Magento, i will close that question, and do a comment on it about the category of that question and where they can post.

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more
>   effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Reputations are doesn't a matter, we are here for helping each other, so that does not a constraint.

> In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Try to spend more time with in the community.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Antley

> What is your position on questions related to third party modules? A simple "I'm for/against them" will not sufice. Please list the reasons.

I’d be apprehensive with questions that relate to 3rd party modules. Even if the module the OP is posting about is popular and well used within the community it is still difficult to replicate any issue due to other modules/configurations possibly affecting the issue the question is relating to.

However, I’d be lenient towards Open Source modules and allow the question to be kept providing the user has provided the necessary steps to reproduce. For paid modules I feel the vendors should be the one fielding issues with their own modules.

> How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

I would warn the user and try to discourage them from generating arguments in their comments and point out why it may be happening. If the user continues then I will suspend their account for a time period.

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I would re-open/un-delete the question and comment with my reasons for doing so.

> What do you think you can do as a moderator to achieve balance between quality content and being welcoming to new members?

Ensuring that our community documentation/wiki is up-to-date and informs new users on how to conduct themselves within the community as well as encouraging high quality questions and answers. Helping new users by commenting on their questions/answers with advice on how to better improve their post as well.

> Do you see any "no-do" actions/activities in this community? If you get a chance to be a moderator here, then what will be your approach to such no->do actions/activities?

I see "no-do" activities as:

1. Copy/pasting other people's answers without giving reference to the original poster for similar/related questions.
2. Changing the original question to invalidate answers already posted.
3. Upvote abuse to cause a user to gain more reputation quickly.

All of these activities will warrant a warning followed by a suspension for any further occurrences.

> How much time you can spend per day for the community? Do you think you will be able to scale up this time when needed if the flag load for a day rises unnaturally and/or the other moderators are not available?

I can see myself easily spending over an hour a day moderatoring for the community, if not more. I can easily scale this up if more moderation is needed over busier times.

> How you can help a Magento developer to write better answers on Stack Exchange?

By having a set of rules in place that are there to encourage quality posting. If a question is answered without following these a comment can be made on the post to provide advice for further answers the user may provide.

> How would you handle a situation where a new user regularly asks questions >that are not related to Magento?

I would close the question for being off-topic. warn the user and provide the correct Stack Exchange link for them to ask their question. If they continued then I would suspend the user's account for a time period.

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Being a moderator means you have more authority as opposed to users with 10k/20k rep and that users will look to you to resolve disputes and issues in the community. Being a moderator comes with more responsibilities as opposed to someone who has a higher rep and requires a higher time commitment.

> In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Moderators, moderate. This involves settling disputes, enforcing rules, keeping the community tidy and organised.